# Using SQLite in Android content providers

Tags: android, sqlite

In my application I am using user dictionary application i want to retrieve words column in user dictionary how can i retrieve words column in my application.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? where does content provider come into play? You want to get word column from query or you want to modify your existing content provider for dictionary?

Comment: We can't even begin to answer without at least seeing your database structure.  Posting that and the code you've tried so far would enable people to try and answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Call the `query` method on your [`SQLiteDatabase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).